# How to create new screen, activate the environment and run python script in crontab

Tags: python, cron, screen

I want to do crontab schedule job to create screen, activate the environment and run python script.

In linux, I did the following comments:

1. `screen -S test`
   inside the screen
2. `cd /home/folder`
3. `export http_proxy=http://proxy.example.com:3128/`
4. `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/miniconda/bin`
5. `source activate /anaconda_env/myenv`
6. `python test.py`
7. exit screen

When I want to run the above 7 procedure in the crontab every 1 month, how can I write in crontab?

Comment: I am curious about the flow, why do you want to have the cron executed in a screen?

Comment: Hello Ban, not cron executed in a screen.
Want to create a scheduler to run python script in the screen.